# Data structure of Threaded comments in mongoose and Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, data-structures, tree

```
{
    "post": {
        "img": "",
        "likes": [
            "60c418582f7066090ced4a51"
        ],
        "comments": [
            {
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "comments": [
                            {
                                "comments": [
                                    {
                                        "comments": [],
                                        "_id": "60d6ab9207c0a573786a9e65",
                                        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                                        "content": "good post 3",
                                        "createdAt": "2021-06-26T04:22:42.337Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T04:22:42.337Z",
                                        "__v": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_id": "60d6962cee10aa73f820b974",
                                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                                "content": "good post 2",
                                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T02:51:24.111Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T04:22:42.622Z",
                                "__v": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "comments": [],
                                "_id": "60d705784ab01c354cf7f445",
                                "userId": "60c15ac41ed8da1ab4efe7f3",
                                "content": "Comment deleted by User",
                                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T10:46:16.813Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T12:29:06.398Z",
                                "__v": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "comments": [],
                                "_id": "60d706febcba957b04406547",
                                "userId": "60c15ac41ed8da1ab4efe7f3",
                                "content": "yes it is a good post 1 from alexane Updated",
                                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T10:52:46.679Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T12:17:58.879Z",
                                "__v": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "60d695b4ee10aa73f820b973",
                        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                        "content": "good post 1",
                        "createdAt": "2021-06-26T02:49:24.426Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T12:30:44.872Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "60d68e32dff84439a4d3b191",
                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                "content": "good post",
                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T02:17:22.625Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T02:49:24.820Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "comments": [],
                        "_id": "60d6c2d917d0b12be44742d2",
                        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                        "content": "nice post 1",
                        "createdAt": "2021-06-26T06:02:01.420Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T06:02:01.420Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "60d6bebf17d0b12be44742d1",
                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                "content": "nice post",
                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T05:44:31.436Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T06:02:01.676Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "comments": [],
                        "_id": "60d87e7df43fed7e4079875e",
                        "userId": "60c15ac41ed8da1ab4efe7f3",
                        "content": "awesome post 1",
                        "createdAt": "2021-06-27T13:34:53.192Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-27T13:34:53.192Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "60d87cb4f43fed7e4079875d",
                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                "content": "awesome post",
                "createdAt": "2021-06-27T13:27:16.299Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-06-27T13:34:53.468Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "60c5a23eb37b425a00968fa9",
        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
        "description": "This is a sample Post 2",
        "createdAt": "2021-06-13T06:14:22.196Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-06-27T13:27:16.577Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I have a threaded comments for a single post which I recursively autopopulated using Mongoose (the code can be found below ). Is it correct to assume the above data structure is a Tree ? If yes, what kind of tree data structure would be the best to implement a a threaded comments to do basic crud such as insert , edit and delete.

```
//Comment.js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const { Schema } = mongoose
    
    const commentObj = {
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            required: true
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            min: 6,
            required: true
        },
        comments: [
            { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }
        ],
    }
    
    const commentSchema = new Schema(commentObj, { timestamps: true });
    
    const autoPopulateChildren = function (next) {
        this.populate('comments');
        next();
    };
    
    commentSchema
        .pre('findOne', autoPopulateChildren)
        .pre('find', autoPopulateChildren)
    
    const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
    module.exports = Comment

//Post.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose

const postObj = {
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        min: 6,
        required: true
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User" 
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment",
        }
    ]
}

const postSchema = new Schema(postObj, { timestamps: true });
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
module.exports = Post
```

Thank you.